# What's the difference between static and stagnation properties?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Difference between static and stagnation properties.

Comment: Please mention your research so far. Also, this looks like a rather broad list-question, which could be made a bit more specific.

Comment: I was going through basics of gas dynamics and couldn't pretty much understand what stagnation properties actually mean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stagnation properties are those possessed by a volume element of gas after it has been decelerated from the free stream velocity to zero. In this case, the kinetic energy it originally had has been converted into potential energy of compression, which means its density and temperature have increased above the static values.